# what is the difference between AddView() and View.Draw()?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-canvas, android-view, android-viewgroup

What is the difference between `AddView()` (*adds views to the layout*) and `View.Draw()` (*adds view to the canvas*) methods, they both add views to the view in the layout, is there any performance difference between the two?

I have a situation where i can add a view from

> 1) touch event

or

> 2) `OnDraw`

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Those are two rather completely different things. `Draw()` graphically draws a `View` to a `Canvas`. That `View` doesn't necessarily have to be attached to any parent. `AddView()` basically just adds a `View` to a parent `ViewGroup`'s collection of children. `AddView()` may very well trigger a layout and redraw, at which point the new child can `Draw()` itself to the provided `Canvas`.

Comment: @MikeM. I should have read the documentation, now i understand the difference 